# Override FosUserBundle template in own bundle, not app/Resources

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

According to this http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

I can override FOSUserBundle templates in the app/Resources directory or create a child bundle.

Is there a way to place these templates into my own bundle directory instead?

I've tried adding:

```
twig:
   debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
   strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
   paths:
       '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/': FOSUSerBundle
```

to my config.yml

Answer (score 0):

No, the template names are hardcoded inside the FOSUserBundle's controllers, thus you are not able to place them in your own bundle. (Unless you overwrite all controllers completely)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Template names are hardcoded in fosub controllers. But,
as a workaround you can include your own template in rewrited one. For sample, do it like this:

```
// app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig
{% include '@YourBundleName/layout.html.twig' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did template overriding for `FosUserBundle` in one of my project developed in `symfony2.3` version.
Please try below code that may help you

**config.yml**

```
twig:
   debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
   strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
```

**FrontBundle/Controller/LoginController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Dhi\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    protected function loginController(array $data)
    {
        $request = $this->get('request');
        return $this->render('FrontBundle:login:login.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**FrontBundle/Resources/views/login/login.html.twig**

```
{% extends "DhiUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
{% block body %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}

        {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

        // Your login form code here

    {% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may look at your versions of FOSUser and Symfony and read this thread : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2439

I've experience this bug which didn't allow me to override FOS templates because they used (in latest version 2.0.0-beta) the namespaced syntax (the one with @ symbol) to link templates. And because of it, before Symfony's 2.7.23 version, you can't override templates by putting the right named file in the same folders as described here : http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

Comment: Include more details in your answer and avoid from just providing some external links.

Comment: I did it, is it better ?

Comment: You don't have any limits for number of characters. Why not copying and pasting (including some edits to avoid from too much content which can be overwhelming) and still have those references. The way it is right now, if anything happens to those links, your answer will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. My config.yml file is below:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/WebBundle/Resources/views/user/": FOSUser
```

I added all FOSUserBundle templates under WebBundle/Resources/views/user/ and made some extend/include changes in all templates and now it works.